# How to get UITableView to extend inside of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

So I have a UIScrollView, and inside of it, a view, and then underneath the view, a UITableView. In viewDidAppear(), I set the UIScrollView to be the height of the tableview plus the height of the view above it. However, now, as I scroll down, the tableview is cut off at the bottom and just stops (I have to scroll inside of the tableview instead of the UIScrollView to access more cells). As you scroll down, the bottom of the scrollview is just blank space. How do I set the bottom of the tableview to match the bottom of the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the UIScrollView height to the absolute height of the UITableView you need to set it to the UITableViewCell height multiplied with the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: /*cellHeight*/ 40 * /*cellsCount*/ 12) // make the tableview has it's full size without scrolling        
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height) // make the scroll view stretch to the hight of the tableView
```

Comment: what are x and y?

Comment: also this is outdated for swift 3

Comment: ok now it works just replace the 40 * 12 with your data and it will work